# iOS On Demand Resources failing on App Store build

Tags: ios, iphone, image, one-definition-rule, on-demand-resources

I have an app where I have some intro screens that I have set up on iOS's new On Demand Resources. It works perfectly while debugging and testing when I build it from my machine to the device. It also works on production builds built from Crashlytics for our testers to test. But now that the app is in the app store the on demand resources are not working. This makes it very hard to test as it still works great in my own testing but the app store version does not work.

When requesting the images I need it appears I am not getting authenticated. Here is what the device logs print out when requesting the images:

> Aug 16 07:15:05 Kevins-iPhone ondemandd[163] : Authentication
>   attempt : 1
>
> Aug 16 07:15:05 Kevins-iPhone ondemandd[163] : Authenticating
>   with prompt style : 1000
>
> Aug 16 07:15:05 Kevins-iPhone ondemandd[163] : Should retry
>   authentication : NO
>
> Aug 16 07:15:05 Kevins-iPhone ondemandd[163] : No tags fetched
>   from set for bundle with url. Tags: {(
>         IntroScreens    )} BundleURL : ...
>
> Aug 16 07:15:05 Kevins-iPhone ondemandd[163] : Invalid tag in
>   set [{(
>         IntroScreens    )}] for BundleURL: ...  Nothing will be pinned.

Any ideas why this is happening would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting up Xcode server to test on demand resources locally?

Comment: I haven't, but don't really know how to set that up

Comment: have you found cause of problem?

Comment: No I ended up taking out the on demand resources and just including them in the app bundle.